# regex no character

Tags: regex

In this text:

```
warning here
there are several types of warnings
in this string warning.gif
at the end warning
end of line warning
```

I want to match every `warning` except `warning.gif`.

I cannot seem to get it to include the last one that has no character (control or otherwise) after it.

using `warnings?[^\.]` gets what I want except for the last warning (on the last line).  I think because there is no character at all after.  How can I get it to include that one?

Comment: What language are you using? Not all regular expression engines are equally powerful, and the syntax differs between engines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have negative lookaheads you can use that:

```
/warnings?(?!\.gif)/
```

This should work in Javascript.

Comment: Good news: Javascript has negative lookaheads.

Comment: This is the winner! Thanks a lot!  I changed the ".gif" to just "."

Comment: Hi Mark, I'd like to add something to this.  I want to NOT include warning where it is preceded by "0 " (zero space), but yes if any other number >0.  
Lastly do not include if there is any other character after warning or warnings except a space/end of line (or I think in my case nothing (no eol control chars).  Can you help with that one?

Comment: I got this to work with other chars besides . after.  now it looks like: warnings?(?!\w)  
Now I just need to make it not include warning where there is a "0 " <zero space> in front, but any other number ok, or nothing.

Comment: ok, here is what I have now:
[^0]\swarnings?(?!\.|\w)
which works great except it does not catch warning if first word on a line. it expects something before it.

Comment: actually that will only miss if warning is the first word in the file, if it's at the beginning of any subsequent line it works.

Comment: Try `(?:^|[^0])` instead of `[^0]`.

Answer (score 1):

## EDITED

I completely misread the question. My apologies.

Here's a corrected solution:

Alternatives can bind more tightly than the eof marker.

---

Example file:

```
warning here
there are several types of warnings
in this string warning.gif
at the end warning
end of line warning
```

Example script:

```
awk '/warnings?$|warnings?[[:space:]]/ { print }' /home/geocar/g.txt
```

---

Original (wrong) answer:

*Use: `/warnings?$/m` - note that the "?" means that the "s" is optional*

Comment: for some reason this did not catch the warning on the first line.

Comment: @iamnotmad: You have something else wrong with your program. I've edited my post to include an example which you can try yourself.

Comment: This regex only matches if the word is at the end of the line, which is not always the case.

Comment: the new one works.  I'd just like to exclude warning where there is a "0 " <zero space> in front of it.

Comment: @iamnotmad: Then use: `/^warnings?$|[[:space:]]warnings?$|^warnings?[[:space:]]|[[:space:]]warnings?[[:space:]]/`